# No Activity found to handle intent (causes FC)

Tags: android, eclipse, android-activity, android-logcat

I have read nearly every single post about the "activity not found to handle intent" error in the stacktrace, but I have been struggling greatly with finding a solution.  Here is the output from the logcat:

```
03-26 00:17:54.617: E/AndroidRuntime(803): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No     Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.SenseiMods.Wallpapers.Gallery }
```

Here is my manifest file:

```
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Gallery"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.SenseiMods.Wallpapers.GALLERY" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

My class is named Gallery.  Which is why I called it by that name.  I'm sure it's something simple.  Thank you for any help you can give.

Comment: where is the code that creates the intent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it is simple :  the action name attribute in your `manifest` file  is `GALLERY` all capital letters

and it seems that you set the action to `com.SenseiMods.Wallpapers.Gallery` in your java code

so change `Gallery` to `GALLERY`

Comment: Thanks! that was the problem.

Comment: AND WHAT ABOUT THIS: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.SEND typ=text/plain pkg=com.google.android.apps.plus (has extras) }