# Google Plus API for android

Tags: android, google-plus, google-play-services

My need is to upload image/video file to Facebook, Picasa, Google+ etc And I have done all Except Google+. And I Have read [This Link](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/). And I have tried with this but its getting [activitynotfoundexception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20393419/activitynotfoundexception-in-google-plus). This exception is coming because there no Google+ Application My Device. But My Application requirement is it should be in-depended from Google+.
So I tried with another method But There is another [exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20471741/code-403-and-reason-forbidden-exception-at-uploading-file-in-google-p). So please help me. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Google+ does not have an independent write API available to general developers - the only way to post to Google+ via an app is to open the Google+ app (preferably using the `Intent` returned by `PlusShare.Builder` as you mentioned).

Answer (score 1):

I'm unlocking this content for you to upload photos to google +.

https://developers.google.com/+/domains/api/activities/insert